# No puedo evitar el erro "can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy utilizand la sigiente función y me salta el error del título en el penúltimo for(donde escribo lo de tuple(new_color_...). Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar,muchas gracias:

```
 def prox_subst(img,color_list,distance):
    hist= [0]*len(color_list)
    width,height=img.size
    new_color_list=[(0,0,0)*len(color_list)]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            color=img.getpixel((x,y))
            index=proximo(color,color_list,distance)
            for i in range (len(color_list)):
                new_color_list[index]=tuple(new_color_list[i]+color[i])
    return (divide_color(new_color_list[i], hist[i]) for i in range(len(hist)))
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Juan Martinez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Cual es la intención de tu código? Puedes explicar lo que querías lograr?

Comment: Es parte de una práctica en la que tenemos que sustituir los colores de la imágen original por los colores más representativos por así decir para que quede una imágen más homogénea y luego obtener esa lista de colores,el problema es que me falla lo de la tupla

Comment: Al ver el código @JuanMartinez, me percaté que en el  `return` se tiene que reemplazar: `(divide_color(new_color_list[i], hist[i]) for i in range(len(hist)))` por `[divide_color(new_color_list[i], hist[i]) for i in range(len(hist))]` sino se obtendrá un error: **<generator object <genexpr>>**, aunque esto no tiene que ver con la pregunta inicial.